# CLI tool built using commander gem doesn't execute correctly when used after being installed

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, executable

So, I have a CLI tool I'm building using the [commander](https://github.com/commander-rb/commander) gem.

The executable successfully executes correctly when used directly from the `bin` folder (`bin/dynamised`), but when I install the gem locally and then run it from the command line (`dynamised`) it doesn't seem to do anything.

If I add `puts 'WORKING'` to the top of the file, I see that but nothing else.

EDIT:

output of `puts [$0, __FILE__].inspect`:

from bin:
`["bin/dynamised", "bin/dynamised"]`

from installed gem:
`["/Users/---------/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/dynamised", "/Users/---------/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/Dynamised-0.1.4/bin/dynamised"]`

[Link to gist](https://gist.github.com/Thermatix/9b0b7b4b49ddb9b6c832a8590130cc4f) containing executable.

Not quite sure what's wrong.

Comment: Try to put `puts [$0, __FILE__].inspect` in the very top of the file and re-execute it. I suspect they differ.

Comment: yeah, that solved it... now I feel a bit stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the very last line of your script to:

```
Dynamised::CLI.new.run if File.basename($0) == File.basename(__FILE__)
```

or simply remove this redundant check:

```
Dynamised::CLI.new.run
```

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I did, removed the check, I'm not sure why I had it in there but it works now, I'll tick this as the answer as it's what I did.